# How can a Linux/Unix Bash script get its own PID?

Tags: bash, scripting, pid

I have a script in Bash called `Script.sh` that needs to know its own PID.  In other words, I need to get PID inside `Script.sh`.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 322, accepted):

The variable `$$` contains the PID.

Comment: How can i get the pid from outside the script , i use `top` but it shows a lot of random processes

Answer (score 104):

use `$BASHPID` or `$$`

See the [manual][1] for more information, including differences between the two.

TL;DRTFM

- `$$` Expands to the process ID of the shell.

  - In a `()` subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.
- `$BASHPID` Expands to the process ID of the current Bash process (new to bash 4).

  - In a `()` subshell, it expands to the process ID of the subshell
    [1]: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables

Answer (score 46):

In addition to the example given in the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) referenced by **Jefromi**, these examples show how pipes create subshells:

```
$ echo $$ $BASHPID | cat -
11656 31528
$ echo $$ $BASHPID
11656 11656
$ echo $$ | while read line; do echo $line $$ $BASHPID; done
11656 11656 31497
$ while read line; do echo $line $$ $BASHPID; done <<< $$
11656 11656 11656
```

Comment: could you please explain what does "<<<" mean? Thanks.

Comment: It redirects a string into the loop (or anything that reads `stdin`). The string is referred to as a "here string".

Answer (score 10):

The PID is stored in `$$`.

Example: `kill -9 $$` will kill the shell instance it is called from.

Comment: `kill -9` (with `-9` flag) is considered to be harmful and only to be used if it is absolutely necessary).

Comment: It's considered "dangerous" because the process does not get a chance to respond to the signal (and possibly clean up after itself). Doing `kill -9 $$` does exactly 1 thing. It kills the **current shell process**. This is useful if you have done something in the shell session that you do not want written to `.bash_history` Like: `docker run -e PASSWORD=hunter2 ircbot`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `$$` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Wherever you are (on an interactive command line or in a script), and in the case you do NOT have access to $BASHPID, you can get access to your current shell pid with this :

bash -c 'echo $PPID'

where simple quotes are essential to prevent premature string interpretation (so as to be sure the interpretation occurs in the child process, not in the current one).
The principle is just to create a child process and ask for its parent pid, that is to say "myself".
This code is simpler than ps-based Joakim solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the process is a child process and $BASHPID is not set, it is possible to query the ppid of a created child process of the running process. It might be a bit ugly, but it works. Example:

```
sleep 1 &
mypid=$(ps -o ppid= -p "$!")
```