# Why does echo $$ return a number?

Tags: bash, echo

Why do I get a number when doing that :

```
echo $$
```

which returns

```
489
```

If I open a new terminal it returns another number. It seems it's related to the pid of the terminal session, but why ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493642/how-does-a-script-know-its-own-pid

Comment: And bash special parameters: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$` means your current PID.

As seen in [Bash Reference Manual - 3.4.2 Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

> $
>
> Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands
>   to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

You can test it by doing `ps -ef | grep 489`, and it will show the process in which you are logged in.

For example in my case:

```
$ echo $$
3470

$ ps -ef | grep 3470
1000      3470  3469  0 10:59 pts/3    00:00:00 -bash    <---- this process
1000      8151  3470  0 15:37 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -ef
1000      8152  3470  0 15:37 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 3470
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how it is defined. `$$` is a special shell variable (like e.g. `$!`, `$_`, `$@`, `$1`, ...) referring to the PID of the invoked shell.

Answer (score 1):

You will find an excellent explanation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/2174320).

> $$ pid of the current shell (not subshell)