# string matches method in java when wanting to compare two dollar signs (not escaping)

Tags: java, regex, dollar-sign

I have the simplest of code thats supposed to compare two string inputs as follows:

```
public class Validate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String re = args[0];

        String input = args[1];

        System.out.println(input.matches(re));
    }
}
```

It works as expected except if your two inputs are `$`and`$`, it just prints out false.  I did hear about how you have to escape any special regex characters, including dollar sign.

But what if you want to compare two dollar signs and print out `true`

Comment: Aren't you looking for `equals` instead of `matches`?

Comment: `String.matches` uses regex and the `$` is important for regex. You should use `String.equals` instead or escape the `$`.

Comment: `$` is a a special character in regex (end of String). You have to escape it

Comment: Firstly in any Linux shell $$ is a special variable, so you would need to use "\$\$" at the very least. Try printing out **argv[0]** before you use it.

Comment: Did you try `input.matches(Pattern.quote(re))`?

Answer (score -1):

In **bash** $$ is substituted by the **ProcessID** a small integer.

Comment: See also **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457166/why-does-echo-return-a-number?lq=1**