# want to print PPID and pid in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

In the below program, I am able to print the ppid  notable to print pid,

I want to know the answer, pid is important so I ndeed to print it

```
#! /bin/bash

echo " a.display PTD of parent and child "
echo " b. copy the file content "
echo " enter your choice "
read ch

case $ch in

a)
    echo " parent pid is $PPID"
    echo " pid is $PID"
;;

b)
    echo "enter a source file"
    read f1
    echo "enter destination file "
    read f2

    if [ -f $f1 ]
    then 
      cp $f1 $f2
else    
    echo "file does not exist"
fi
;;
esac
```

Comment: Have you looked in these places:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-display-process-pid-under-linux-unix/
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-return-pid-of-a-last-command-in-linux-unix/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493642/how-does-a-linux-unix-bash-script-know-its-own-pid ?

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. Of *which* process do you want to print the PID? The process of the bash script itself is stored in `$$`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have sudo priveleges you can get process id using pgrep. see `man pgrep`

```
....  
a)
echo " parent pid is $PPID"

#you can get child id from parent process id.
pid=$(sudo pgrep --parent $PPID)
##now you have process id as pid

echo " pid is $pid"

b)...
```

*i don't have enough reputation to comment and answer with `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use $$ to get the PID.

```
a)
echo " parent pid is $PPID"
echo " pid is $$"
;;
```

I believe this is what you wanted to do.